# Postgres: ERROR: prepared statement "add_post" does not exist

Tags: postgresql

I'm probably not looking straight and missing something obvious, but why is the following prepared statement not being executed?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_post (userId BIGINT, fbUserId CHARACTER VARYING(128), fbUserName CHARACTER VARYING(250), gender GENDER, 
                googlePlaceId CHARACTER VARYING, googlePlaceName CHARACTER VARYING(250),
                geom geometry(Point,4326), statusText TEXT, statusImg TEXT)
    RETURNS void AS $$
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO "post"."post"(user_id, fb_user_id, fb_user_name, gender, google_place_id, google_place_name, geom, posttype_id, status_text, status_img) 
    VALUES (userId, fbUserId, fbUserId, gender, googlePlaceId, googlePlaceName, geom, (SELECT posttype_id FROM "post"."posttype" WHERE code = 'LIVE'), statusText, statusImg);
    END;
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

EXECUTE add_post(1, '001', 'Thomas Cop', 'm', '4f89212bf76dde31f092cfc14d7506555d85b5c7', 'Hard Rock Cafe', ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(4.35292, 50.84618), 4326),
    'Status text 1 Tomas Cop', '/img/001.png');
```

The error received is:

```
ERROR:  prepared statement "add_post" does not exist
```

I'm executing this in the pgadmin console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`EXECUTE` is for prepared statement check here for examples https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-prepare.html#SQL-PREPARE-EXAMPLES

if you want execute a function you do

```
SELECT yourFunction(<parameters>);
```

Comment: No problem, Sometimes just writing the question help you to find the answer ;)